# Splash Screen Added - App Name Changed

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm working on an Android app and have just added the Splash Screen as I will be loading from SQLite on start-up...

After telling the AndroidManifest that I'd like to have my Splash activity as my LAUNCHER, it seems that it's changed the name that my app is downloaded under.

The app is now called Splash, has anyone had this problem before?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.codedaykcrunningapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.codedaykcrunningapp.Workout"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_workout" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.codedaykcrunningapp.Widget"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.codedaykcrunningapp.Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you please show your manifest?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: where is the changed name `Splash` has shown in `project explorer`

Comment: It's changed on my phone where I am running the App...

Comment: uninstall ur app from ur phone clean ur project and run it

Comment: No luck, but when I uninstalled it had the correct name. It's just what it gets installed as...

Answer (score 8):

Android is using the label name of your launcher activity so change that to your app name

change

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.codedaykcrunningapp.Splash"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
    ....
```

to

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.codedaykcrunningapp.Splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
    ....
```

this will fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

> After telling the AndroidManifest that I'd like to have my Splash
>   activity as my LAUNCHER, it seems that it's changed the name that my
>   app is downloaded under.

BCOZ

If you have a "launcher activity" with [label name] & "application tag" also with a different [label name] then Android will take the [label name] from the Launcher Activity.
For more information you can see this [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#iconlabel).

Answer (score 0):

The app name is set in the file Android Manifest, please check the item application and attribute android:label.

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
...
</application>
```

Comment: This is what it is set as...I have double-check my strings.xml as well and the app_name is correctly set